# Threejs Как создать объект let monkey = new obj()

Tags: javascript, three.js

Всем привет!

Создаю объект,

```
var obj = function (obj) {

  let scope = this;
  this.root = new THREE.Mesh();
  let loader = new GLTFLoader();

  loader.load('models/'+ obj, function ( gltf ) {
    scope.root.geometry = gltf.scene.children[0].geometry;  
    scope.root.material = gltf.scene.children[0].material;      
  });
}

let monkey = new obj('monkey'); 
scene.add(monkey.root);  //!
```

`**как добавить в сцену scene.add(monkey); в место scene.add(monkey.root);???**

```
var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  monkey.root.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
```

Спасибо за ваше понимание и внимание

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: я хочу добавлять в сцену вот так let monkey = new obj('monkey');
        scene.add(monkey); для этого написал объект и работает только так как написано выше

Comment: почитайте про наследование и прототипы

Answer (score 0):

Метод scene.add принимает в качестве аргумента объекты типа `THREE.Mesh` ([док](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh)), поэтому можно воспользоваться наследованием:

```
class Monkey extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'Monkey';
    let loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('models/'+ obj, function ( gltf ) {
      super.geometry = gltf.scene.children[0].geometry;  
      super.material = gltf.scene.children[0].material;      
    });
  }
}
```

Теперь вы можете спокойно передать ваш `Monkey` в scene, потому что это `THREE.Mesh`:

```
let monkey = new Monkey();
scene.add(monkey);
```

В данном случае это не лучший вариант, так как у вас имеется отложенная инициализация объекта (асинхронная загрузка данных в конструкторе), поэтому лучше отделить мух от котлет и сделать загрузку отдельно, по завершении которой, произвести инициализацию объекта-меша-обезьянки:

```
  let scene = ...; // Инициализация сцены

  let monkey = null; 

  let loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('models/'+ obj, function ( gltf ) {
    monkey = new THREE.Mesh(
      gltf.scene.children[0].geometry,
      gltf.scene.children[0].material
    );
    // После загрузки данных, добавляем объект-mesh в сцену
    scene.add(monkey);
  });
```

Тогда анимация будет выглядеть так:

```
var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  if( monkey ) // <- пока monkey не будет создано вращать нечего
    monkey.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, только почему же  первый вариант  не лучший, например let sun = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xccccff,1); scene.add( sun );

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален вариант 1 не работает ругается на super

Comment: @НиколосКейдж  используйте второй, с первым разберусь когда доберусь до компа (возможно он вообще не рабочий)

Comment: я пытаюсь чтобы было так let model= new obj('monkey'); -  monkey это название модельки которую хочу получить, далее это удобно поместить в цикл и создать большой массив models['monkey', 'elephant'...]  . Мой вариант почти то что мне надо, только вынужден писать root -scene.add(model.root);

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, спасибо Alexander Chernin